# kubernetes set list of all physical nodes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I've setup Kubernetes with the steps below. Everything looks fine - but it's running on a single node/server.

Now I want to take the next step for running on multiple nodes. I wonder where should I configure my physical servers ip's so I could create the pod in more than one physical server.

I run:

```
hack/local-up-cluster.sh
```

then (In another terminal):

```
cluster/kubectl.sh config set-cluster local --server=http://127.0.0.1:8080 --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true
cluster/kubectl.sh config set-context local --cluster=local
cluster/kubectl.sh config use-context local
```

And:

```
cluster/kubectl.sh create -f run-aii.yaml
```

**my run-aii.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: aii
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: aii
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: aii
        image: localhost:5000/dev/aii
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5144
        env:
        - name: KAFKA_IP
          value: kafka
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /root/script
          name: scripts-data
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /home/aii/core
          name: core-aii
          readOnly: false
        - mountPath: /home/aii/genome
          name: genome-aii
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /home/aii/main
          name: main-aii
          readOnly: false
      - name: kafka
        image: localhost:5000/dev/kafkazoo
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /root/script
          name: scripts-data
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /root/config
          name: config-data
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: scripts-data
        hostPath:
          path: /home/aii/general/infra/script
      - name: config-data
        hostPath:
          path: /home/aii/general/infra/config
      - name: core-aii
        hostPath:
          path: /home/aii/general/core
      - name: genome-aii
        hostPath:
          path: /home/aii/general/genome
      - name: main-aii
        hostPath:
          path: /home/aii/general/main
        - mountPath: /home/aii/main
          name: main-aii
          readOnly: false
      - name: kafka
        image: localhost:5000/dev/kafkazoo
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /root/script
          name: scripts-data
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /root/config
          name: config-data
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: scripts-data
        hostPath:
          path: /home/aii/general/infra/script
      - name: config-data
        hostPath:
          path: /home/aii/general/infra/config
      - name: core-aii
        hostPath:
          path: /home/aii/general/core
      - name: genome-aii
        hostPath:
          path: /home/aii/general/genome
      - name: main-aii
        hostPath:
          path: /home/aii/general/main
```

Additional info:

```
[aii@localhost kubernetes]$   cluster/kubectl.sh get pod
NAME                   READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
aii-3934754246-yilg3   2/2       Running   0          59s

[aii@localhost kubernetes]$   cluster/kubectl.sh describe pod aii-3934754246-yilg3
Name:           aii-3934754246-yilg3
Namespace:      default
Node:           127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1
Start Time:     Sun, 29 May 2016 16:58:20 +0300
Labels:         pod-template-hash=3934754246,run=aii
Status:         Running
IP:             172.17.0.4
Controllers:    ReplicaSet/aii-3934754246
Containers:
  aii:
    Container ID:       docker://71609cfd8e33c01a81a36770d12d884443a12b4c2969b95e3042d9dee4fb455b
    Image:              localhost:5000/dev/aii
    Image ID:           docker://sha256:7e70fbb724962b2f23c9439a1c00356deb551fd96ffd27a8afa6340fc903e735
    Port:               5144/TCP
    QoS Tier:
      memory:           BestEffort
      cpu:              BestEffort
    State:              Running
      Started:          Sun, 29 May 2016 16:58:23 +0300
    Ready:              True
    Restart Count:      0
    Environment Variables:
      KAFKA_IP: kafka
  kafka:
    Container ID:       docker://6eb891e5968cf1106b26a9f3f7db881683a8e15dd59b1858435715580c90656c
    Image:              localhost:5000/dev/kafkazoo
    Image ID:           docker://sha256:b78e60582cbc8d3c4946807baf59552d110c7802c8204157e6fba509b96bc11c
    Port:
    QoS Tier:
      cpu:              BestEffort
      memory:           BestEffort
    State:              Running
      Started:          Sun, 29 May 2016 16:58:24 +0300
    Ready:              True
    Restart Count:      0
    Environment Variables:
Conditions:
  Type          Status
  Ready         True
Volumes:
  scripts-data:
    Type:       HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:       /home/aii/general/infra/script
  config-data:
    Type:       HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:       /home/aii/general/infra/config
  core-aii:
    Type:       HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:       /home/aii/general/core
  genome-aii:
    Type:       HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:       /home/aii/general/genome
  main-aii:
    Type:       HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:       /home/aii/general/main
  default-token-5z9rd:
    Type:       Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: default-token-5z9rd
Events:
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                    SubobjectPath           Type            Reason          Message
  ---------     --------        -----   ----                    -------------           --------        ------          -------
  1m            1m              1       {default-scheduler }                            Normal          Scheduled       Successfully assigned aii-3934754246-yilg3 to 127.0.0.1
  1m            1m              1       {kubelet 127.0.0.1}     spec.containers{aii}    Normal          Pulling         pulling image "localhost:5000/dev/aii"
  1m            1m              1       {kubelet 127.0.0.1}     spec.containers{aii}    Normal          Pulled          Successfully pulled image "localhost:5000/dev/aii"
  1m            1m              1       {kubelet 127.0.0.1}     spec.containers{aii}    Normal          Created         Created container with docker id 71609cfd8e33
  1m            1m              1       {kubelet 127.0.0.1}     spec.containers{aii}    Normal          Started         Started container with docker id 71609cfd8e33
  1m            1m              1       {kubelet 127.0.0.1}     spec.containers{kafka}  Normal          Pulling         pulling image "localhost:5000/dev/kafkazoo"
  1m            1m              1       {kubelet 127.0.0.1}     spec.containers{kafka}  Normal          Pulled          Successfully pulled image "localhost:5000/dev/kafkazoo"
  1m            1m              1       {kubelet 127.0.0.1}     spec.containers{kafka}  Normal          Created         Created container with docker id 6eb891e5968c
  1m            1m              1       {kubelet 127.0.0.1}     spec.containers{kafka}  Normal          Started         Started container with docker id 6eb891e5968c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to setup a multi-node cluster, there are numerous ways to do that (http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/).

If you want a local solution on your machine, the vagrant way or the docker way is pretty straight forward.

If looking for a cloud, then GCE is the next easiest (https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/).

Once you have your multi-node cluster setup, then when you deploy your pod, it will be scheduled to a node in the cluster.

The only *gotcha* to be careful of given your manifest above, is you are using `HostPaths` for all your volume mounts. This is fine when you know what machine you are running the pod on, however, you should be abstracting yourself away from that.

To better solve you'll need to look into some persistent volumes that are not host specific. BUT for now, you can get it working. =)